# Android: Why clicking on notification of intent with backstack destroys parent MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

Below is my sendNotification function which will be called from a Service, it's working fine creating a notification and showing it on the status bar. But when the app is already running (I'm at MainActivity),clicking on the notification to open ConversActivity, the parent MainActivity is destroyed, and when im pressing back button from ConversActivity, MainActivity is recreated. Please help me to avoid this behavior when the app is running (either in fore/background)

Btw, this is the correct behaviour when the app is killed or not running, coz MainActivity is created from the backstack, which is correct. But when the app is running, why MainActivity is destroyed and re-created? This is not efficient and cause slowness to the app due to app initiation from MainActivity 's onCreate.

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".View.MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>


<activity
        android:name=".View.ConversActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_convers"
        android:parentActivityName=".View.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".View.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

-

ConversActivity.java (back button):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //onBackPressed();
            //finish();
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

-

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context, String dname) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConversActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("dname", dname);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
                    // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
                    // followed by DetailsActivity itself
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("You've got a message!")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("@" + dname + ": " + msg))
                    .setContentText("@" + dname + ": " + msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 100}) //off-on-off-on-off
                    .setLights(Color.GREEN, 3000, 3000)
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    ;
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(dname, 0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked when you move  ConversActivity to mainactivity your mainactivity should be come in onresume not in oncreate ??

Comment: yes, I did put a Log.d and debug in the onCreate and onDestroy of the MainActivity, the moment i click on the notification, i see onDestroy is triggered, then when i click back-button from ConversActivity, the onCreate got triggered again. Could be something wrong with my backstack and pendingIntent ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it looks like `TaskStackBuilder` adds the following flags to the root Activity `Intent`:

```
    intents[0].addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
            IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
```

If you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse) about how to set up the user's expected navigation behaviour for Notifications, it seems that what they want you to do is have the Notification create a "fresh task" which will contain the Activity you are launching and an appropriate back-stack so that the user will be able to back up through a "fresh" copy of your application back to the HOME screen. I'm afraid that the standard behaviour of `taskAffinity` is liable to make it impossible to preserve your original app's task and also start another one from the Notification. That may not be what you want anyway.

What is happening here is that, if your app is running and you click on the Notification, the existing task is being brought to the foreground, cleared (all Activities are finished/destroyed) and then the topmost Activity is launched into this task (in your case `ConversActivity`). The back stack is then set up so that if the user clicks BACK, it will recreate the previous Activities in the back stack, one at a time, until the user ends up at the HOME screen.

The above should explain what is happening and why.

To solve your problem, I'd suggest that you do the following:

Do not setup the backstack for the Notification. Just have the Notification launch `ConversActivity`.

In `ConversActivity.onCreate()` do the following:

```
super.onCreate(...);
if (isTaskRoot()) {
    // Started from a Notification and the app is not running, restart the app with back stack
    // Here create a launch Intent which includes the back stack
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversActivity.class);
    // Copy extras from incoming Intent
    intent.putExtras(getIntent());
    // Now launch this activity again and immediately return
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
        .startActivities();
    return;
}
```

This should just launch `ConversActivity` on top of your existing app (if it is open), and should launch it with the correct back stack if your app is not running.

Comment: omg im so glad this is totally working for me, thank you thank you so much =))

Answer (score 0):

If your mainactivity not running than your notification data will come in mainactivity than you can pass data from mainactivity to conversactivity.If mainactivity running tha your data directly pass in conversactivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity

 {
  public static boolean isMainActivityRunning;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    isMainActivityRunning = true;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    isMainActivityRunning = false;
}
}
```

do some change in your PendingIntent

```
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Intent intent=null;
 if(!MainActivity.isMainActivityRunning){
 intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 }
else{
 intent = new Intent(context, ConversActivity.class);
 }

intent.putExtra("dname", dname);
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                    requestID , intent , Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);
```

Comment: but when im doing this way, im losing my backstack, this is ok when the app is running.
But when the app is killed (or when i press Back button from within MainActivity),then pressing Back Button from ConversActivity will get me straight back to the home screen. (send notification is called from a Service)

Comment: hi Montu, somehow isMainActivityRunning always return false to me, note that im running sendNotification from a service, and the context passed to sendNotification is from [getApplicationContext()].

I addwatch isMainActivityRunning from MainActivity it returns true, but Log.d for the sendNotification always show "false" for isMainActivityRunning. There's something wrong with getting the isMainActivityRunning's value from a service.

Comment: do you start your service before onresume ?? because isMainActivityRunning's value is being true in this method

Comment: i started my service in onstart even of MainActivity, after all the authentication is approved. btw, i've got the solution from David. Thank you so much for your help though =))